# Count the number of identical values ​in different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in which I want to count the number of identical values ​​in different columns. But I don’t understand yet how to implement it. Please tell me.

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Field1  | Field_A | Field_B | Field_C | Field_D |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Value_A |    0    | 0       | 0       | 0       |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Value_A |    0    | 14      | 0       | 14      |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Value_A |    12   | 0       | 12      | 0       |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Value_A |    0    | 12      | 0       | 0       |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Value_A |    0    | 0       | 0       | 0       |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Value_A |    1    | 12      | 0       | 1       |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Value_A |    0    | 0       | 14      | 0       |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

in the end I want to get the following result

```
+---------+-------+-------+
| Field_A | Value | Count |
+---------+-------+-------+
| Value_A | 12    | 4     |
+---------+-------+-------+
| Value_A | 14    | 3     |
+---------+-------+-------+
| Value_A | 1     | 2     |
+---------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acheive it using CROSS APPLY

```sql
DECLARE @table table (Field1 VARCHAR(10), Field_A int,Field_B int, Field_C int, Field_D int)

INSERT INTO @table 
values
('Value_A',0    , 0       , 0       , 0      ),
('Value_A',0    , 14      , 0       , 14     ),
('Value_A',12   , 0       , 12      , 0      ),
('Value_A',0    , 12      , 0       , 0      ),
('Value_A',0    , 0       , 0       , 0      ),
('Value_A',1    , 12      , 0       , 1      ),
('Value_A',0    , 0       , 14      , 0     );

SELECT Field1,t.Field, count(*) as countOfFields  FROM @table
cross apply
(
VALUES (Field_A),(Field_B), (Field_C),(Field_D)
) as t(Field)
GROUP BY Field1, t.Field
```

**Another approach using UNPIVOT**

```sql
SELECT Field1, val, COUNT(*) FROM @table
unpivot (val for Field in ([Field_A],[Field_B],[Field_C],[Field_D])) AS U
GROUP BY Field1, VAL
```

```
+---------+-------+---------------+
| Field1  | Field | countOfFields |
+---------+-------+---------------+
| Value_A |     0 |            19 |
| Value_A |     1 |             2 |
| Value_A |    12 |             4 |
| Value_A |    14 |             3 |
+---------+-------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a union approach here:

```
SELECT Field1, Field AS Value, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM
(
    SELECT Field1, Field_A AS Field WHERE Field_A <> 0 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT Field1, Field_B FROM yourTable WHERE Field_B <> 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT Field1, Field_C FROM yourTable WHERE Field_C <> 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT Field1, Field_D FROM yourTable WHERE Field_D <> 0
) t
GROUP BY Field1, Field;
```

Note that since you have this requirement, it might imply that the four field columns in your original table really belong in a single column, with perhaps another new column which tells the type of that column data.